# Python to convert string number to decimal places

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using below code to convert Bytes to KB-MB-GB-TB

```
a = 2048 * 1073741824
def bytes_2_human_readable(number_of_bytes):
    if number_of_bytes < 0:
        raise ValueError("!!! numberOfBytes can't be smaller than 0 !!!")

    step_to_greater_unit = 1024.

    number_of_bytes = float(number_of_bytes)
    unit = 'bytes'

    if (number_of_bytes / step_to_greater_unit) >= 1:
        number_of_bytes /= step_to_greater_unit
        unit = 'KB'

    if (number_of_bytes / step_to_greater_unit) >= 1:
        number_of_bytes /= step_to_greater_unit
        unit = 'MB'

    if (number_of_bytes / step_to_greater_unit) >= 1:
        number_of_bytes /= step_to_greater_unit
        unit = 'GB'

    if (number_of_bytes / step_to_greater_unit) >= 1:
        number_of_bytes /= step_to_greater_unit
        unit = 'TB'
    print number_of_bytes
    precision = 1
    number_of_bytes = round(number_of_bytes, precision)

    b = str(number_of_bytes) + '' + unit
print b
bytes_2_human_readable(a)
```

I Get output for 2TB is like 2.0TB

and for 1.5TB is 1.5TB only

Now other side or command output for 2TB i get 2TB
and for 1.5TB i get 1.50TB

Now i need compare the values.

```
a = 1.0TB
b = 1TB
c = 1.5TB
d = 1.50TB
```

All above variables are in string format

Now I need to match (Note below code does not work it just example to show what i am expecting)

```
if a == b:
   print "Should match even if a = 1.0TB and b 1TB"
else:
   print "B size is different value if value is more or less"
if c == d:
   print "Should match even if c = 1.5TB and b 1.50TB"
else:
   print "d size is different value if value is more less"
```

Please help what is best of converting 1.0TB to 1TB and 1.5TB to 1.50TB

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to match 1.0TB == 1TB what is best way of converting

Comment: So, to be clear, all your variables `a,b,c,d` are strings? And you want to convert them to what?

Comment: Just modified the question, Yes all values are strings and I need to convert 1.0TB to 1TB and 1.5TB to 1.50TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I assume your problem is simply how to remove trailing 0s on your values and not how to compare TBs with GBs etc.

Well, thankfully python is really good in handling strings.

```
def remove_trailing_zeros(string):
    suffixes = ['KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']

    for s in suffixes:
        string = string.replace('.0'+s, s)
        string = string.replace('0'+s, s)

    return string
```

Comment: However, I would use a different approach. I would create a class called something like `DataSize` where I would store the `number_of_bytes` and I would implement a method (or more) called `to_human_readable_format()` which would return the `str` representation. This way you can have comparisons between the class instances which is easy and use the string representation only for printing.